# Skip empty value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, row

I have running script in google sheets for submitting data, but I have no idea how to skip empty values

Here is my script :

```
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("FORM");
  var dataS= ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  
  var values = formS.getRange(8,1,20,5).getValues();
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,3,20,5).setValues(values);
  
}
```

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean "skep empty values" Your code looks like it's grabing 20 rows and 5 columns... what do you want to happen?

Comment: Please be specific what 'empty value' stands for? Skip empty row?

Comment: yeah I mean skip empty rows

Comment: there is empty values between 20 rows, and I don't want to get that empty values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  var values = formS.getRange(8,1,20,5).getValues();
  values = values.filter(e=>e.join('') !== '');
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,3,values.length,5).setValues(values);
```